# How round in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

when we use SUM on a data table gives a 1 or 2 cents of difference due to rounding in Postgres.

We are using Postgres 9.4, the field data types is `numeric` with `19,3`
and the result have to be with two decimals.

for example:

```
 15.309
 10.111
  5.005
```

and the result must be: `30.43`

the query is:

```
SELECT SUM(fcv_total_comprobante)::numeric(19,2) 
FROM factura_venta 
WHERE DATE(fcv_fecha_comprobante) BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30'
```

the result given is `30.42` (because is `30.425`) and must by `30.43`

which would be the best way to round a number to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the attribute/column being summed as type money or as type numeric.  If defining numeric you'll need to specify the percision.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-money.html#DATATYPE-MONEY-TABLE